# Wifi Think Penguin USB and Debian 9 won't work

Tags: debian, wifi

I have recently acquired a new desktop and bought a usb wireless adapter in order to use internet wireless. I have decided to choose [this model](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-wireless-n-usb-adapter-gnu-linux-tpe-n150usb) as I’ve had issues with most of my wifi cards in the past because of proprietary drivers.
Excited to have internet “out of the box”, I haven't succeeded yet to make it work

I’ve browsed the internet for a while and tried the below options without success either.

- Installed firmware-atheros
- Tried to plug the adapter in different usb slots (you never know…)
- Lit a candle this morning….

  `lsusb`:

  ```
  Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
  Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
  Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
  Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  ```

`ifconfig`:

```
 enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
            inet6 fe80::e497:3b91:8b6d:e8cc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether 00:21:9b:05:44:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 917  bytes 415883 (406.1 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 933  bytes 125581 (122.6 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
            device interrupt 20  memory 0xfdfc0000-fdfe0000  

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
            inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
            inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
            loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
            RX packets 458  bytes 288915 (282.1 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 458  bytes 288915 (282.1 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlxbc307eadc950: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.0.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
            inet6 fe80::d7b:20:66ff:ec5e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
            ether bc:30:7e:ad:c9:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 30  bytes 3449 (3.3 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 38  bytes 6994 (6.8 KiB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`dmesg | grep usb`:

```
    [    0.730508] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.730519] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.736116] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.756135] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    0.756137] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.756138] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [    0.756140] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 ehci_hcd
    [    0.756141] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.7
    [    0.776086] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [    0.776088] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.776089] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [    0.776091] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 ehci_hcd
    [    0.776092] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.7
    [    0.958342] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.958344] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.958346] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.958347] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.958348] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
    [    0.958948] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.958950] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.958951] usb usb4: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.958953] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.958954] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.1
    [    0.959425] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.959427] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.959428] usb usb5: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.959431] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.959432] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.2
    [    0.959944] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.959945] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.959948] usb usb6: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.959950] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.959951] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
    [    0.960472] usb usb7: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.960476] usb usb7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.960478] usb usb7: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.960479] usb usb7: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.960480] usb usb7: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.1
    [    0.960986] usb usb8: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
    [    0.960988] usb usb8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.960989] usb usb8: Product: UHCI Host Controller
    [    0.960993] usb usb8: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 uhci_hcd
    [    0.960994] usb usb8: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.2
    [    1.084025] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [    1.248827] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
    [    1.248831] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
    [    1.248833] usb 1-4: Product: UB93
    [    1.248836] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
    [    1.248839] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 12345
    [    1.772023] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
    [    1.962055] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=1005
    [    1.962060] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    1.962063] usb 5-1: Product: Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
    [    1.962066] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Dell
    [    2.272033] usb 5-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
    [    2.429050] usb 5-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2011
    [    2.429055] usb 5-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.429058] usb 5-1.1: Product: Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard
    [    2.429061] usb 5-1.1: Manufacturer: Dell
    [    2.508616] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [    2.508618] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [    2.509846] input: Dell Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.2/usb5/5-1/5-1.1/5-1.1:1.0/0003:413C:2011.0001/input/input3
    [    2.568293] hid-generic 0003:413C:2011.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.2-1.1/input0
    [    2.579106] input: Dell Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.2/usb5/5-1/5-1.1/5-1.1:1.1/0003:413C:2011.0002/input/input4
    [    2.636145] hid-generic 0003:413C:2011.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [Dell Dell Multimedia Pro Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.2-1.1/input1
    [    2.656025] usb 5-2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
    [    3.051070] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c016
    [    3.051072] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [    3.051074] usb 5-2: Product: Optical USB Mouse
    [    3.051075] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
    [    3.067475] input: Logitech Optical USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.2/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:046D:C016.0003/input/input5
    [    3.067558] hid-generic 0003:046D:C016.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech Optical USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.2-2/input0
    [    9.717257] usb 1-4: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
    [    9.717281] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
    [    9.755269] usb 1-4: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw
    [   10.037093] usb 1-4: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
```

Thank you

Comment: can you add lsusb log? check ifconfig iwconfig log and post. also if possible portion of dmesg where usb is detected . It will help debug the issue. I accept it should have worked out of the box let's find out why it didn't.

Comment: I added the result of these 3 commands in my original post, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: [Penguin Wireless N USB Adapter for GNU / Linux (TPE-N150USB) Debian Firmware Install](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-wireless-n-usb-adapter-gnu-linux-tpe-n150usb-debian-firmware-install)

> To use Debian 7 (Wheezy) or Debian 8 (Jessie) or Debian 9 (Stretch) with the adapter(s) do the following:
>   You don't need to upgrade your kernel just copy the firmware to your `/lib/firmware`

As root:

```
cd /lib/firmware
wget https://www.thinkpenguin.com/files/ath9k_firmware_free-version/htc_9271.fw
wget https://www.thinkpenguin.com/files/ath9k_firmware_free-version/htc_7010.fw
reboot
```

> **Also Note**: If you are on Debian 9 (Stretch) and you see a list of access points, but can't connect try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

> Then restart network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works now. I believe the fix was to add this line as it is the main difference to what I was doing before:
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0